# How to get data from REST API using angularJS custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am trying to get Json data from REST Api ("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/") using angularJS custom service but it is not showing the data. Although when I am directly typing the url in the browser it shows some data.

Here is the angular service code.

```
angular.module('myapp.service',[])
       .service('testService', function ($http) {

     //get All NewsLetter
     this.getPosts = function () {
         return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
     };
     });
```

and controller

```
angular.module('myapp.controller',[])
       .controller('testController',function($scope,testService){

        $scope.posts={};
 function GetAllPosts() {
               var getPostsData = testService.getPosts();

               getPostsData.then(function (post) {
                   $scope.posts = post.data;

               }, function () {
                   alert('Error in getting post records');
               });
           }
       });
```

When I debugged it in the browser . it shows service function is returning undefined data.

Although when I tried to get the data directly in the controller using the code

```
angular.module('myapp.controller',[])
       .controller('testController',function($scope,testService,$http){
         $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .success(function (data) {
        $scope.posts=data ;
    });  

       });
```

it works fine,Can any one please tell me where i am making the mistake in the service.

I have used a parent module having all the dependency injections

```
angular.module('myapp',['myapp.controller','myapp.service']);
```

Comment: Have you enabled cors on your server?

Comment: you forgot to import the myapp.service module into your myapp.controller module. That's why testService cannot be resolved and doesn't work. Add it as a dependency: angular.module('myapp.controller',['myapp.service']).Although I do wonder why you're creating 2 seperate modules for this?

Comment: @fikkatra I have used a parent module which has all the dependency injection.Sorry for not showing the whole code in the question initially. I have made the changes in the question. So dependency injection is not the issue for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you shared, you never invoked the `GetAllPosts` method in the controller.  See working plunker below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/YSTWwS?p=preview

P.S. - I had to make the URL https for plunker

Comment: I have used a parent module which has all the dependency injection.Sorry for not showing the whole code in the question in the beginning. I have made the changes in the question. So dependency injection is not the issue here I guess.

Comment: Is it that you also did not invoke the ```GetAllPosts``` method in your controller?

Comment: @simba - Don't you hate the small things when you clearly understood the hard parts like DI :)

Comment: @simba, also, while the dependency injection you added does work, it can bite you in the butt one day because your true dependency for ```myapp.service``` is ```myapp.controller```.  There is no harm in putting the dependency in the ```myapp``` and ```myapp.controller``` modules since angular will only create a single instance of ```myapp.service``` which is shared between the two items.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I will make the necessary changes and keep in mind in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
service function is returning data, you can check by adding another then() to promise object returned by service.
function GetAllPosts() {
var getPostsData = testService.getPosts();
getPostsData.then(function (post) {
$scope.posts = post.data;
}, function () {
alert('Error in getting post records');
}).then(function(){
console.log($scope.posts); 
});
}
make sure that you are checking response inside then()
```